# Multicore and operating systems

Tags: operating-system, multicore, parallel-processing

What changes, if any, would an operating system need to implement to take full advantage of multicore systems? I ask this because I'm doing some research on parallel algorithms and the scheduler, for example, gets in my way of more theoretically-driven work. Are there other issues?

Comment: I suspect that whole cache/memory synchronization thing can be ... fun. (Beyond the normal level of interrupt handling.)

Comment: @pst: Thanks. Yes, but I can model penalties/miss rates and hierarchies more than I can model the scheduler (my archenemy right now)... the scheduler may choose to run everything on one die (when other dies are idle), and other crazy things that make a whole lot of sense, but render many of my algorithms almost non-deterministic in costs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what it has to do for taking full advantage of SMP, it's also convenient to be able to have some knowledge of hierarchy and relative costs, see this [LWN article about *scheduling domains*](http://lwn.net/Articles/80911/).

Answer (score 1):

Thread migration, load balancing, core affinity for threads. If "full advantage" means optimal usage then load balancing in particular probably makes it practically impossible.
If "full advantage" has some leeway a few simple heuristics can probably go a long way.
Any "non-uniform access" resource (such as if one particular core handles all interrupts
for a network interface for instance) will add complications to the load balancing decisions.